# Save copies as .PDF & .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to save copies of the workbook but don't know how to set the file type when saving, this code makes the files but they're corrupt and cannot be opened.

```
Sub Saves1()

'Store Answers
Dim SavePdfAnswer As String
Dim SaveXlsxAnswer As String
SavePdfAnswer = VBA_CS.Range("C2")
SaveXlsxAnswer = VBA_CS.Range("C3")

'Store File Path And Names
PdfFilePath = VBA_CS.Range("M2") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("F9") & ".pdf" 'File path for pdf file
ExcelFilePath = VBA_CS.Range("M2") & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("F9") & ".xlsx" 'File path for excel xlsx file

'Save as pdf
If SavePdfAnswer = "Yes" Then
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs PdfFilePath
End If

'Save as excel xlsx
If SaveXlsxAnswer = "Yes" Then
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ExcelFilePath
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to use `SaveAs` and not `SaveCopyAs` to be able to specify the `FileFormat` of your output file! Use macro recorder to find the FileFormat you need! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for pdf:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="path\pdf_from_excel.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

for xlsx:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "path\excel_file_name.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Hope this works whats needed

Answer (score 1):

A quick example:

```
Sub SaveFile()
Dim tmpPth As String

On Error GoTo errorhandle

tmpPth = FilePath & FileName


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=tmpPth & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, openAfterPublish:=False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs tmpPth & ".xlsm"

Exit Sub

errorhandle:
MsgBox ("Something went wrong")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to know how system do this you can register macros.
Ms Word generated this code :

```html
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fileName.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
         OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
        True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: MS Excel:  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fileName.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False